# Run two instances in Node-Red: install alternative version

Tags: node.js, node-red

I need to run 2 instances of Node-Red on the same laptop. I found this fork: https://github.com/aryeharmon/node-red
In this post the author gave some information: [How to embed multiple instances of node-red in node app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203799/how-to-embed-multiple-instances-of-node-red-in-node-app)

I don't know how to install his fork. Do i have to download and install it as i did with the classic version of Node-Red? Anything else? It's the first time i try to use a fork, thanks in advance.

Comment: I run as many as 6 instances of node-red on my laptop at a time -- the trick is to have each project in its own directory, with its own settings.js and package.json files. The advantage is that each instance can include different nodes and dependent packages, and can run different versions of those nodes and packages. The big disadvantage is that each instance must run on its own Http port number. If this would also work for you, I can document my setup a bit more in an answer below...

Comment: Yes SteveR, i'd appreciate that. Now i can just run node-red on the default port. Which files i have to edit, and what are the right command? Thank you.

Comment: Nick beat me to it -- essentially, I have a directory for each project, and each settings.js file uses a different uiPort number. Each directory also has its own `flow_xxx.json` and `package.json` file. Assuming your laptop has a Windows OS, you may want to create a .bat file for starting each instance, using the command like `node C:\path\to\node-red\red.js -v -u C:\path\to\my\node_red_project`

Comment: Thank you! I have Linux OS and i made It following your's and knolleary's instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to install a fork of node-red to support running multiple instances.

When you run node-red you can specify what settings file and user data directory it will use via the command-line options:

```
node-red -s /data/userDirectory/settingsFile.js -u /data/userDirectory
```

Give each instance its own settings and user data directory - specifying a different port to listen on in the settings file.