# ui not active when the project is not selected

Tags: node-red

I have 2 projects: project1 and project2.

When I'm working with project 2, dashboard of the project 1 is not reachable or active. Is there a way to view dashboard of project 1 while working with project 2 which also has a dashboard?

- Node-RED version: 0.18.3 (project functionality enabled)
- node.js version: 6.12.3
- npm version: 3.10.10
- Dashboard version: 2.8.1

Comment: You would need to have two instances of node-red running on different ports --  see https://stackoverflow.com/q/48814470/5640850

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was answered in the [issue](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/1640) you raised.

No, you can only load one flow/project at a time on a single instance of Node-RED, this means you can not edit project 2 while running project 1